# Return no row - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

There is a condition if not satisfied then I just want to return no rows as my application will pick no row and will show no record msg on front end. Is there any other professional way?

For now I am using following query to return no row.

```
select 0 
where 1 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when you return no rows, you are still returning a schema. And most applications expect the same schema to be returned regardless of the number of rows. Even when 0 rows are returned.

If you can change the SQL in @SqlStr that you are executing with `sp_executesql`, I would insert into a temporary table in that query and then return the results of selecting from that temporary table:

```
Select * from #myTempTable where <conditionRequiredForResults>
```

Comment: In my case if condition is not satisfied, even there is no need to create any temp table or need to execute any sp_executesql. Whole procedure code is in if part and in else just want a query or trick which returns no row. My solution is not look likes a professional one. Please suggest.

Comment: @ShikhilBhalla you way looks perfectly fine - I've seen that technique used many times.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to return no rows on your frontend and return nothing. Neither message nor row.
You just need to use if statement to avoid returning anything to your frontend

```php
require_once 'db_connection.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE <your filtering Condition>";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // If row to be fetched is more than 0
  // Return something Example:
  echo "Rows detected";
} else {
  // If there is no row to be fetched
  // Return nothing
}
```

And this should return nothing if no row fetched from database

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 0 NULL
```

This will return a schema with one unnamed column and no rows. It is readable for anyone that you wanted deliberately to return nothing, because you used TOP 0 and NULL. Not a thing.

This still returns a schema because each query must have a schema to return so you can specify

```
SELECT TOP 0 '',0,GETDATE()
```

if you want first column to be string, second integer, third date/datetime etc. but still to return no rows.

```
SELECT TOP 0 NULL
```

return a schema with one unnamed column that is of integer type, 32-bit integer that is.